Mad max styled sci fi where rowed identical men touch shiny object and disappear
I remember watching this as a kid must be from the 80's
Well I remember a desert scene, there was a kind of camp.
I have the feeling it was kind of post apocalyptical (like mad max) of some sort. There was a row of identical men which where kind of stupid/ignorant and touched (I believe) a shiny object, after holding it they disappeared or went to dust (I don't know if they got really tiny or died). The thing is the others on the row did the same thing without thinking that they would die.

The movie "Mom and Dad Save the World " (1992) includes such a scene:

During the wedding ceremony, a detachment of Spengo's soldiers go into the desert to finish the rebels, but find their camp deserted, and one by one they fall victim to one of the Light Grenades which has been left on Dick's pallet. (Source: Wikipedia)

Here's the scene (the relevant part starts around 0:45):




wow thank you so much!

It is really funny how all this time my memories where and how the movie really looked like! Forge about the mad max thing haha. Thanks a lot again!

@Daniel If this is the correct answer, please click on the check mark to approve it and resolve your question.
